# Truncated output from PHP, no errors

Tags: apache-2.2, php, debian, sugarcrm

I've installed SugarCRM Community Edition on Debian 6.0.3 connecting to MSSQL with FreeTDS. I can use the system as normal except for one deal-breaker problem. On login, I get a blank page outputted. I get a `200 OK`, but the HTML is truncated after about 12 lines. After this I can manually navigate to the site root and use the site as normal, without errors.

Nothing shows up in the Apache log and nothing telling in the Sugar application log (I've enabled debug messages so there's a lot of normal SQL activity logged in there).

My php.ini has

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
display_errors = On
```

I've tried setting `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT` but all I got from that was a flood of code style warnings with no errors.

What else can I do to investigate this truncation problem?